# SpriteKit, Image limitation 4088 Pixels ?

Tags: sprite-kit, background-image

I'm having problems with my background image, 
So far my background image size is 768(width) X 4088(height), and it's perfectly scrolling verticlly.
I'm trying to make my image higher, which means I want to extend the 4088 to 5166, but when I edit the picture I'm getting black screen. when I edit it back around 4000 pixels it's working again.
**So do Sprite kit has limitation with the height of the images ?**

the reason I want my background that long is so I can add object to it graphically. 
Since I'm new to the sprite kit, I know it can be done with code but I don't want to add more nodes to my project, plus my background image size is around 430kb.

Comment: are you just resizing the canvas to 5166 high? or actually stretching the background image to the new height?

Comment: I remember the limit is somewhat below 2048 pixels (for whatever reason) on devices that only support 2048x2048 pixel textures. I suppose it's the same with devices that support at most 4096x4096 pixels, probably 4088 is there just to leave enough padding at the texture borders. So no, there's not a way around this limitation as it's a hardware limitation. You can always split an image in two and use two sprites, one a child of the other at the appropriate offset.

Comment: Marcb - I was just resizing it with photoshop. LearnCocos2D - Thank you for the detailed answer. I would mark it as an answer but you just comment. I guess I need to create another sprite and join them together.